# How to make writing articles on blogger centering?

Tags: html, web, blogger

I have a Blogger article that looks like this:

[image]

I want to centralise part of the content like this (edited with Photoshop):

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this other than using by pressing the spacebar multiple times?

Comment: What i see there looks like a table in the bottom. You can center a table using default css.

Answer (score 0):

Use the text field options you have above. However, you may want to check if it's a tabel try to "align:right/left". Press the html button near compose at the top bar and have fun!

Also you may need to show us the proper code if you can't figure it out!

Comment: Ini adalah Kode Html dari blog saya                                                  <table style="text-align: Left; width: 70%;"><tbody>
<tr>     <td><div style="text-align: left;">
Nama</div>
</td>              <td><div style="text-align: left;">
:</div>
</td>  <td><div style="text-align: left;">
Zain Javadd Malik</div>
</td>   </tr>
<tr>     <td><div style="text-align: left;">
Tanggal Lahir</div>
</td>     <td><div style="text-align: left;">
:</div>
</td>     <td><div style="text-align: left;">
12 Januari 1993</div>
</td>   </tr>
<tr>     <td><div style="text-align: left;">

Comment: everywhere you see text-align: left change it with 'text-align: center;' and change the width from 70% to 100%.